# Cómo calcular frecuencia de texto que se encuentra en varias columnas de un dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Tengo un dataframe con 47 columnas con registros del mismo tipo (string). A continuación pongo un ejemplo con solo 3 columnas:

```
d1= 
 C1   C2   C3  C4
 A2   A1   A5
 NaN  NaN  A4
 A1   A2   A3
 NaN  NaN  NaN  A5
```

Requiero crear una salida con la frecuencia de aparición de cada valor de texto que se presenta en todas las columnas del dataframe

Para mi ejemplo la salida sería:

```
S1=

 A1   2
 A2   2
 A3   1
 A4   1
 A5   2
```

Agradezco en lo que me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una forma bastante cómodo es "aplanar" el `dataframe` en un `ndarray` con [`ravel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ravel.html#pandas-series-ravel) para luego contar las ocurrencias:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

datos = [["A2", "A1", "A5", np.nan],
         [ np.nan,  np.nan, "A4", np.nan],
         ["A1", "A2", "A3", np.nan],
         [ np.nan,  np.nan, np.nan, "A5"],
         ]

df = pd.DataFrame(datos, columns=["C1", "C2", "C3", "C4"])
print(pd.Series(df.values.ravel()).value_counts())
```

Salida:

```
A5    2
A2    2
A1    2
A4    1
A3    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Muchas gracias es lo que necesito.